# Keeping data update safe

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have seen many websites (including SO and my websites) to store rows id of data extracted from database in a HTML attribute. I know that it can be edited by the user at client side and maybe sent to server-side to update the data according. Take this query as example and remember, it is for upvoting comments:

`SELECT comment_id, comment FROM comments`

A normal person will do the printing like this:

`<td data-commentid="<?php echo $row['comment_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></td>`

and the output:

```
<td data-commentid="1">+1, beat me to it.</td>
<td data-commentid="2">Damn! What is this?</td>
...
```

When it is displayed to some hacker type user, he will try to edit the commentid with something like 250 and will click upvote button and our innocent script will accept it and will upvote the other comment with id 250 although it was visually for comment with id 1 or 2.

**Question**:

Is there any way to get rid of this? You can turn your console on and inspect SO also when you change its attribute referencing to comment important information, it seems to update the db with the updated attribute's id.

Comment: Authentication? If the user didn't post comment #250 they shouldn't have access on the server-side to modify it.

Comment: you cannot prevent someone from using client-side tools to fiddle with data stored in THEIR browser on THEIR computer. It's the Wild Wild Web - never trust anything coming from a client. If you don't want comment #250 being upvoted, then don't allow upvotes on it if the user isn't on a page where comment #250 should be upvotable.

Comment: Your choices are to use a GUID or other non-incrementable data type for the comment key, or implement a security check on the submitted values, which may be impossible for anonymous users.

Comment: @ceejayoz I didn't post your comment, but I can upvote it, right?

Comment: @Dexa If I want to manually change the ID and upvote the wrong comment, who cares?

Comment: @ceejayoz No one care, but he shouldn't deny possibility to upvote other people posts/comments. Your comments make sense and I actually use it in every day programming, just not in the case OP asked.

Comment: @ceejayoz Hey, guys what if I am providing comment edition feature? The data written in the input will update the comment id 250. There is no way that I can validate whether that comment id was edited or not.

Comment: In that case use what @ceejayoz said.

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar: Again, you don't care what was originally displayed; you only care what the user is allowed to edit.  The server needs to know that independently.

Comment: @SLaks Yeah, I have all that code already in my mind but I am still anxious. I need some time to think. Thanks to all the guys who commented.

Answer (score 7):

That isn't actually an attack.

There is no difference between performing your "hack" and actually viewing comment #250 and upvoting it.

If the user changes the ID or action to something he isn't allowed to do, you  must use server-side authorization / access control to deny the request.

In short:

## Never trust any information provided by the client.

Always verify that the input makes sense, and that the user is allowed to take the action.

Comment: The logical consequence of never trusting is **validate everything**.